# sql Error 1064 (42000) Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message(
  id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  userid INT NOT NULL,
  date Date NOT NULL,
  text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  ('id')
  FOREIGN KEY ('userid') REFERENCES users('id'));
```

I was just wondering if someone could help me in identifying a syntax error as I can not create a table.

Comment: when you have `auto-increment`, no need to `NOT NULL`

Comment: error solved or still persist??

Comment: see my answer... You won't get error... also provide structure for `users` table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to put `,` after the primary key declaration.

Update: I guess it should be

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  userid INT NOT NULL,
  date Date NOT NULL,
  text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id));
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id'),
  FOREIGN KEY ('userid') REFERENCES users('id'))' at line 6

Comment: @Ricki Does your `users` table have an `id` column?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for MS SQL Server?  If you get MS SQL Server Studio, you can script stuff which gives you an idea:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[message]') AND type in (N'U'))
CREATE TABLE message(
id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
userid INT NOT NULL,
date Date NOT NULL,
text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (id),
FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id))
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You query should be as below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message (
  id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  userid INT NOT NULL,
  date Date NOT NULL,
  text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id));
```

Provided you have `id` as a primary key in `users` table.

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INT PRIMARY KEY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS message(
  id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  userid INT NOT NULL,
  date Date NOT NULL,
  text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  ('id'),
  FOREIGN KEY ('userid') REFERENCES users('id')
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

Note the `,` after `PRIMARY KEY ('id')`.

#### Small trick

You don't have to specify foreign keys in table definitions. It's practical when you do it like this (because dump may export tables in order that foreign keys will fail on creating/inserting):

```
CREATE TABLE 1; -- With references to table 2
CREATE TABLE 2;
INSERT INTO 1;
INSERT INTO 2;
ALTER TABLE 1 ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES 2 2(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of your table, May be message is an in-built keyword in MySQL.

Update to this: I guess it should be

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myMessage (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  userid INT NOT NULL,
  date Date NOT NULL,
  text varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users(id));
```